# How do I get words left and right of an underscore from a strings in another column? Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have concatenated all .csvs in my directory into one big dataframe and one of the columns is the filename of each file.

These are my file names:

```
['Accelerometer-2011-05-30-09-36-50-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

 'Accelerometer-2011-05-30-08-35-11-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

 'Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-45-50-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

 'Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-42-22-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

 'Accelerometer-2011-05-31-15-16-47-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

 'Accelerometer-2011-05-30-21-55-04-brush_teeth-m2.txt',

 'Accelerometer-2011-04-11-13-28-18-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

etc...]
```

I want to create another column called ['Action'] and it would pull the words left and right of the underscore from the file names. So in this instance it would be "brush_teeth".

How would I do this in python?

Comment: Do all your files follow the same naming pattern? `"a-b-c-action_name-x-y-z.txt"`?

Comment: @Guimoute Yes, all of them follow the same naming pattern!

Comment: So use `split(‘-‘)[3]` or whatever number you need.

Comment: You can use regex `\W(\w+_\w+)\W`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, depending on file size, that you do all the wrangling in vanilla python, before loading into pandas, as the speed will be faster. My two cents though. This is one way of solving the problem. I believe the options in the comments section will more than solve this. It is indexed at -2 because of the location.

```
text = ['Accelerometer-2011-05-30-09-36-50-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

        'Accelerometer-2011-05-30-08-35-11-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

        'Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-45-50-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

        'Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-42-22-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

        'Accelerometer-2011-05-31-15-16-47-brush_teeth-f1.txt',

        'Accelerometer-2011-05-30-21-55-04-brush_teeth-m2.txt',

        'Accelerometer-2011-04-11-13-28-18-brush_teeth-f1.txt',]

(pd.DataFrame(text)
.assign(Action = lambda x: x[0].str.split('-').str[-2]))

       0                                                Action
0   Accelerometer-2011-05-30-09-36-50-brush_teeth-...   brush_teeth
1   Accelerometer-2011-05-30-08-35-11-brush_teeth-...   brush_teeth
2   Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-45-50-brush_teeth-...   brush_teeth
3   Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-42-22-brush_teeth-...   brush_teeth
4   Accelerometer-2011-05-31-15-16-47-brush_teeth-...   brush_teeth
5   Accelerometer-2011-05-30-21-55-04-brush_teeth-...   brush_teeth
6   Accelerometer-2011-04-11-13-28-18-brush_teeth-...   brush_teeth
```

Comment: This solution will work if there are always the same number of hyphens after the match phrase. It will fail if there is occasionally a different number of hyphens. I like the elegance of the lambda function.

Comment: @Matt, Thanks for the feedback. The OP said the files had the same pattern, hence the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments. Depending on the stability of the naming pattern, you don't need regex at all. You could solve it like this:

```
mylist = ['Accelerometer-2011-05-30-09-36-50-brush_teeth-f1.txt',
 'Accelerometer-2011-05-30-08-35-11-brush_teeth-f1.txt',
 'Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-45-50-wash_face-f1.txt',
 'Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-42-22-brush_hair-f1.txt',
 'Accelerometer-2011-05-31-15-16-47-wash_hair-f1.txt',
 'Accelerometer-2011-05-30-21-55-04-iron_clothes-m2.txt',
 'Accelerometer-2011-04-11-13-28-18-make_bed-f1.txt']

output = []
for i in mylist:
    result = i.split("-")
    for z in result:
        if "_" in z:
            output.append(z)

print(output)
>>> ['brush_teeth', 'brush_teeth', 'wash_face', 'brush_hair', 'wash_hair', 'iron_clothes', 'make_bed']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex to extract the value before the file extension that is also not equal to a dash using a positive look ahead.

```
df['file_name'].str.extract(r'(\w+(?=\s*-\w+\.[^\.]))')
```

---

```
print(df)
                                           file_name       action
0  Accelerometer-2011-05-30-09-36-50-brush_teeth-...  brush_teeth
1  Accelerometer-2011-05-30-08-35-11-brush_teeth-...  brush_teeth
2  Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-45-50-brush_teeth-...  brush_teeth
3  Accelerometer-2011-06-02-10-42-22-brush_teeth-...  brush_teeth
4  Accelerometer-2011-05-31-15-16-47-brush_teeth-...  brush_teeth
5  Accelerometer-2011-05-30-21-55-04-brush_teeth-...  brush_teeth
6  Accelerometer-2011-04-11-13-28-18-brush_teeth-...  brush_teeth
```